# Deleting item from cart session. Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, session

When I add products to my cart through session I want to be able to delete them from my cart one by one. How I'm supposed to do that ? This is my `CartController`

```
public function add(Request $request, $id)
{
    $product_from_db = Product::find($id);
    $product = [];
    $product['id'] = $id;
    $product['title'] = $product_from_db->title;
    $product['image'] = $product_from_db->image;
    $product['slug'] = $product_from_db->slug;
    $product['price'] = $product_from_db->price;
    $product['quantity'] = $request->input('quantity');
    $request->session()->push('cart', array_merge((array)Session::get('cart',[]), $product));
    flash()->success('Prekė sėkmingai pridėtą į krepšelį.');
    return redirect('/prekes');
}

public function show()
{
    $products = session('cart');
    $subtotal = [];
    return view('cart.show')->with(array(
        'products'    => $products,
        'subtotal' => $subtotal
    ));
}
```

This is my cart:

```
                        @foreach($products as $p)
                        <tr>
                            <td class="col-md-6">

                                <div class="media">
                                    <a class="thumbnail pull-left" href="#"> <img class="media-object" src="{{URL::to($p['image'])}}" style="width: 72px; height: 72px;"> </a>
                                    <div class="media-body">
                                        <a style="padding-left: 2%" href="{{URL::to('prekes/'.$p['slug'])}}" class="text-warning"><strong>{{$p['title']}}</strong></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </td>
                            <td class="col-md-1" style="text-align: center">
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="quantity" value="{{$p['quantity']}}">
                            </td>
                            <td class="col-md-1 text-center"><strong>{{number_format($p['price'], 2, '.', ',')}} €</strong></td>
                            <td class="col-md-1 text-center"><strong>{{number_format($p['price']*$p['quantity'], 2, '.', ',')}} €</strong></td>
                            <td class="col-md-1">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> DELETE ITEM
                                </button></td>
                        </tr>
                        @endforeach
```

Can you give me some example how I'm supposed to delete item that I want from a cart ?

I've tryed to do this:

```
public function delete($id)
{
    $product = session::forget('cart', $id)->first();
    $product->destroy($id);
    return redirect()->back();
}

<a href="{{URL::to('jusu-prekiu-krepselis/trinti-preke/'.$p['id'])}}" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Remove
                                    </a>
```

I get this error: `Call to a member function first() on null`

Okay when I do this it removes the product from database not from the session.

Now when deleting I get this error: `Undefined index: image` in my view.

Comment: `$product = session::forget('cart.'.$id);`

Comment: @Autista_z `Call to a member function destroy() on null`

Comment: Is the destroy necessary? The forget should remove product from session

Comment: Now I don't get error, the page refreshes but the product doesnt delete from cart @Autista_z

Comment: If you try `$product = session::get('cart', $id)` or `$product = session::get('cart.'.$id)` did you get the product?

Comment: @Autista_z Yes, I got it

Comment: Maybe I need to set another id when I add product to cart ? Not the original from DB?

Comment: try `$product = session::pull('cart', $id)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To delete specific item with `$id` change your

```
public function delete($id)
{
    $product = session::forget('cart', $id)->first();
    $product->destroy($id);
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

with

```
public function delete($id)
    {
        $products = session('cart');
        foreach ($products as $key => $value)
        {
            if ($value['id'] == $id) 
            {                
                unset($products [$key]);            
            }
        }
        //put back in session array without deleted item
        $request->session()->push('cart',$products);
        //then you can redirect or whatever you need
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: It clearly starts to working. But now I'm getting that small error: `Undefined index: image `

Comment: Where is that error? In View or controller? which line?

Comment: MY BAD! IT WORKS! haha.. I forgot to add IF statement if there are no products! You saved my ass 2nd time TY

Comment: No problem. Glad to help you again :)

Comment: hm.. it still throws that error even if I set IF statement. `@if(count($products))`

Comment: I think you should check that by `if(isset($products))` and later check count and all

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113839/discussion-between-labas-gamepage-visogero-and-kukec).

Comment: Can you get back in our chat ? :)